# WPF | VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(this) on collapsed parent

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-tree, visualtreehelper

I have a "huge" `Control` where ~50% of it is `collapsed`. You can switch by a property to hide the `visible` part and show the `collapsed` one.

Now when the `Control` is loaded, I try to find all `FooControl`s in the `visible` and `collapsed` part of the control. The problem is, that only the `FooControl`s of the `visible` part are found. If I `debug` the code, I can see `FooControl`s in the parent Control of the collapsed part.

Can you give me a hint how to solve this problem?

I need to change a `Property` of `FooControl` after it's loaded. I also need to be dynamic, because it comes with a `behavior`.

Comment: When the Visibility of a UIElement is set to Collapsed, it is removed from the visual tree. That's why the VisualTreeHelper won't be able to find collapsed elements. I don't know what you are trying to do but you will need to find another way.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simply to use [Logical Tree Helper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.logicaltreehelper(v=vs.110).aspx) , Visual Tree helper finds all the objects that are visible, while logical can see all controls made, you might have to refine your code a bit but as you haven't given any more information, I can't help.